# p:selectOneMenu keeps focus

Tags: jsf, primefaces

There seems to be a bug in Primefaces v6.1 when using p:selectOneMenu, it keeps the focus when displaying a modal dialog. You can use the arrow keys up/down to change the selectOneMenu selection. When i replace p:selectOneMenu with h:selectOneMenu it works as expected. Any idea how a can move the focus to the input1 field?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"  
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>      
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <h:form id="form">
     <!-- PF('statusWidget').blur();document.activeElement.blur(); -->
     <p:selectOneMenu id="status" widgetVar="statusWidget"
                   onchange="PF('dlg').show();" value="test1">
       <f:selectItem itemValue="test1" itemLabel="TEST_1"/>
       <f:selectItem itemValue="test2" itemLabel="TEST_2"/>
       <f:selectItem itemValue="test3" itemLabel="TEST_3"/>
     </p:selectOneMenu>
     <!-- onShow="document.activeElement.blur();" -->      
     <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" focus="input1">
       <p:inputText id="input1" widgetVar="test"/>
     </p:dialog>
   </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean that even the `focus="input1"` does not help?

Comment: @Kukeltje Right, it does not work even with focus="input1".

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by adding a delayed call to focus().

```
onchange="PF('dlg').show();setTimeout(function() { $('#form:input1').focus()  },10)"
```